# Need help, How to convert bool type data in C++ WriteFile()?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having trouble rewriting files, I'm getting this error. maybe someone can tell me how to convert the datatype so that the file can be rewritten

```
.\wInaPi.cpp: In function 'INT main(INT, CHAR**)':
.\wInaPi.cpp:30:54: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
30 |     PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER image_dos_header = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) file_read;
                      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

.\wInaPi.cpp:76:63: error: invalid conversion from 'BOOL' {aka 'int'} to 'LPCVOID' {aka 'const void*'} [-fpermissive]

           76 |     WriteFile(PEFile, file_read, file_size, &returned_bytes, NULL);
              |                       ^~~~~~~~~
              |                       |
              |                      BOOL {aka int}
        
    In file included from C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winbase.h:18,
                     from C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:70,
                     from .\wInaPi.cpp:1:
    
    C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/fileapi.h:186:62: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'WINBOOL WriteFile(HANDLE, LPCVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED)'
    
    186 |   WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI WriteFile (HANDLE hFile, LPCVOID lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
              |
```

part of my code

```
HANDLE PEfile = CreateFileA(target_process, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if (PEfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{  
       DWORD file_size = GetFileSize(x_file, NULL);  
       PBYTE file_buffer = PBYTE(LocalAlloc(LPTR, file_size)); 
       DWORD returned_bytes;
       BOOL file_read = ReadFile(x_file, file_buffer, file_size,  &returned_bytes, NULL);
    if (file_read == TRUE && returned_bytes == file_size) 
    {
      if (SetFilePointer(PEfile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) !=    INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
     { 
      WriteFile(PEfile, file_read, file_size, &returned_bytes, NULL);  // got error here 
     } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] so we can see the types of the variables you're using.

Comment: I added part of my code above

Comment: You need to pass `file_buffer` to `WriteFile()`, instead of `file_read`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I see it, too tired. thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what `file_read` is, but the compiler tells you that:

- you should not try to cast it to  `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`;
- `WriteFile` needs a pointer as a second parameter: `WriteFile( PEFile, &file_read,...`.

**[Edit - new information added to the question]**

`file_read` is the result of `ReadFile` which is a `BOOL` (success or failure). Most likely you do not want to write this, anyhow: the third parameter must be the size of the data you are trying to write:
`WriteFile(PEfile, &file_read, sizeof(file_read), &returned_bytes, NULL);`

This will fix your compiling problem but it won’t fix the logic. And we cannot help you since it is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe
`WriteFile(PEfile, file_buffer, file_size, &returned_bytes, NULL);`?